# Load a variable into a dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In PySpark, I am trying to load a dataframe from a string variable.

My variable is a multi line text..

```py
string_data = """
 Name|age|city
 david|23|London
 krish|24|Bali
 john|56|Goa
"""
```

I wanted to load this data into a dataframe in PySpark.
Thought of using datasets but they are not available in PySpark.

Using Pandas, I used to write like this:

```py
string2 = StringIO(string_data)

df = pd.read_csv(string2,sep='|')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string by newline characters, parallelize that into an RDD, and feed that into `spark.read.csv`.

```
df = spark.read.csv(sc.parallelize(string_data.split('\n')), sep='|', header=True)

df.show() 
+-----+---+------+
| Name|age|  city|
+-----+---+------+
|david| 23|London|
|krish| 24|  Bali|
| john| 56|   Goa|
+-----+---+------+
```